# Add temporary record based on distinct record

Tags: sql, row-number, partition-by

I'm a newbie on SQL and tried using different keywords but unable to find the solution that I'm trying to get.

Say that I have a table name [JobSales] with the following data (note that I have more columns in real database).

| LineType | Project | Unit | MajorCode | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Summary** | **A101** | **01** | **1-001** | **20** |
| --trans | A101 | 01 | 1-001 | 10 |
| --trans | A101 | 01 | 1-001 | 10 |
| **Summary** | **A101** | **01** | **2-002** | **30** |
| --trans | A101 | 01 | 2-002 | 15 |
| --trans | A101 | 01 | 2-002 | 15 |
| **Summary** | **B999** | **01** | **1-001** | **100** |
| --trans | B999 | 01 | 1-001 | 40 |
| --trans | B999 | 01 | 1-001 | 35 |
| --trans | B999 | 01 | 1-001 | 25 |
| **Summary** | **B999** | **01** | **5-001** | **100** |
| Summary | B999 | 01 | 5-001 | 100 |

Is it possible for me to add a temporary record based on Distinct records on 2 columns?

For example, every time there's a record on [Project] and [Unit], I need to create a dummy record with [MajorCode] = '9-999'

Thus Final Table is going to look like this (below)

| LineType | Project | Unit | MajorCode | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Summary** | **A101** | **01** | **9-999 (Dummy/Temporary Record)** | **NULL** |
| **Summary** | **A101** | **01** | **1-001** | **20** |
| --trans | A101 | 01 | 1-001 | 10 |
| --trans | A101 | 01 | 1-001 | 10 |
| **Summary** | **A101** | **01** | **2-002** | **30** |
| --trans | A101 | 01 | 2-002 | 15 |
| --trans | A101 | 01 | 2-002 | 15 |
| **Summary** | **B999** | **01** | **9-999 (Dummy/Temporary Record)** | **NULL** |
| **Summary** | **B999** | **01** | **1-001** | **100** |
| --trans | B999 | 01 | 1-001 | 40 |
| --trans | B999 | 01 | 1-001 | 35 |
| --trans | B999 | 01 | 1-001 | 25 |
| **Summary** | **B999** | **01** | **5-001** | **100** |
| Summary | B999 | 01 | 5-001 | 100 |

EDIT after trying with Jon Armstrong

```
WITH cteJobScrub 
        (
             [OUnit Code]
            ,[Project_ProjID]
            ,[Project Code]
            ,[Project Name]
            ,[Phase]
            ,[Unit]
            ,[Unit Status]
        ) AS 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                     [OUnit Code]
                    ,[Project_ProjID]
                    ,[Project Code]
                    ,[Project Name]
                    ,[Phase]
                    ,[Unit]
                    ,[Unit Status] 
                FROM [someDBName].[db].[tJobScrub]
            )
    SELECT   'Summary' AS [Line Type]
            ,[OUnit Code]
            ,[Project_ProjID]
            ,[Project Code]
            ,[Project Name]
            ,[Phase]
            ,[Unit]
            ,[Unit Status]
            , NULL AS [Model]
            , NULL AS [Model Description]
            , NULL AS [Elev]
            , NULL AS [Model + Elev]
            , NULL AS [Actual Close]
            , '0-0000' AS [Major Code]
            , 'Dummy Major Code' AS [Major Description]
            , NULL AS [Latest Estimate]
            , NULL AS [Invoiced Amount]
            , NULL AS [Open Balance]
            , NULL AS [Invoiced + Open]
    FROM cteJobScrub
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 
       JobScrub.[Line Type]
      ,JobScrub.[OUnit Code]
      ,JobScrub.[Project_ProjID]
      ,JobScrub.[Project Code]
      ,JobScrub.[Project Name]
      ,JobScrub.[Phase]
      ,JobScrub.[Unit]
      ,JobScrub.[Unit Status]
      ,JobScrub.[Model]
      ,JobScrub.[Model Description]
      ,JobScrub.[Elev]
      ,JobScrub.[Model + Elev]
      ,JobScrub.[Actual Close]
      ,JobScrub.[Major Code]
      ,JobScrub.[Major Description]
      ,JobScrub.[Latest Estimate]
      ,JobScrub.[Invoiced Amount]
      ,JobScrub.[Open Balance]
      ,JobScrub.[Invoiced + Open]
    FROM [someDBName].[db].[tJobScrub] as JobScrub
    LEFT JOIN [someDBName].[dbRems].[project] as B with(nolock) on B.[projid] = JobScrub.[Project_ProjID]

    WHERE B.[compcode] = '1007'
    ORDER BY JobScrub.[Lot],JobScrub.[Major Code],JobScrub.[Minor Code]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "add a temporary record".  Modifications to tables are not "temporary".

Comment: Sorry for being unclear...from the original table, create a temporary table. But with the additional record that I'm trying to accomoplish

Comment: You do know that the summary rows should not be in your table? As they are just results from other rows, you shouldn't store them. Redundancy can lead to inconsistencies in a database and should hence be avoided.

Comment: And what is your DBMS? You should always tag SQL requests with the DBMS in question. Brackets around names are non-standard. Are you using SQL Server? (And is the `comp_code` really a string or why do you compare with the string `'1007'` rather than with the number `1007`. Always use the appropriate datatypes. You can get sometimes undesired results, if you don't.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner   I don't know what system the database is using for, but I'm using SQL Server Management Studio to write the queries (sorry...not a techie person, neither am I the admin for the database, and very new to SQL). with regard to comp_code, yes it is a string, thus the '1007'

Answer (score 1):

Note: You didn't specify a database. The following provides general logic you might use.

Since rows in tables have no implied order, I've provided that order explicitly in this test case:

The original table `test`:

```
+----+----------+---------+------+-----------+--------+
| id | LineType | Project | Unit | MajorCode | Amount |
+----+----------+---------+------+-----------+--------+
|  1 | Summary  | A101    | 01   | 1-001     |     20 |
|  2 | --trans  | A101    | 01   | 1-001     |     10 |
|  3 | --trans  | A101    | 01   | 1-001     |     10 |
|  4 | Summary  | A101    | 01   | 2-002     |     30 |
|  5 | --trans  | A101    | 01   | 2-002     |     15 |
|  6 | --trans  | A101    | 01   | 2-002     |     15 |
|  7 | Summary  | B999    | 01   | 1-001     |    100 |
|  8 | --trans  | B999    | 01   | 1-001     |     40 |
|  9 | --trans  | B999    | 01   | 1-001     |     35 |
| 10 | --trans  | B999    | 01   | 1-001     |     25 |
| 11 | Summary  | B999    | 01   | 5-001     |    100 |
| 12 | Summary  | B999    | 01   | 5-001     |    100 |
+----+----------+---------+------+-----------+--------+
```

The SQL to populate `test2`, which can be created any way you wish. The id column has auto_increment behavior, which can be done in several ways depending on your database.

```
INSERT INTO test2 (LineType, Project, Unit, MajorCode, Amount)
WITH cte1 (Project, Unit) AS (SELECT DISTINCT Project, Unit FROM test)
SELECT 'Summary', Project, Unit, '9-999 (Dummy)', null FROM cte1
 UNION ALL
SELECT LineType,Project,Unit,MajorCode,Amount FROM test
;
```

The result:

```
SELECT * FROM test2 ORDER BY Project, amount IS NOT NULL, id;

+----+----------+---------+------+---------------+--------+
| id | LineType | Project | Unit | MajorCode     | Amount |
+----+----------+---------+------+---------------+--------+
|  1 | Summary  | A101    | 01   | 9-999 (Dummy) |   NULL |
|  3 | Summary  | A101    | 01   | 1-001         |     20 |
|  4 | --trans  | A101    | 01   | 1-001         |     10 |
|  5 | --trans  | A101    | 01   | 1-001         |     10 |
|  6 | Summary  | A101    | 01   | 2-002         |     30 |
|  7 | --trans  | A101    | 01   | 2-002         |     15 |
|  8 | --trans  | A101    | 01   | 2-002         |     15 |
|  2 | Summary  | B999    | 01   | 9-999 (Dummy) |   NULL |
|  9 | Summary  | B999    | 01   | 1-001         |    100 |
| 10 | --trans  | B999    | 01   | 1-001         |     40 |
| 11 | --trans  | B999    | 01   | 1-001         |     35 |
| 12 | --trans  | B999    | 01   | 1-001         |     25 |
| 13 | Summary  | B999    | 01   | 5-001         |    100 |
| 14 | Summary  | B999    | 01   | 5-001         |    100 |
+----+----------+---------+------+---------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you Jon for your reply.

Quick question, say if I have 100 columns in the original table, would I need to list all of the columns in the 'INSERT'?

Comment: @David.L No.  Only the columns used/required by the query logic.  You can adjust your `CREATE TABLE` statement to reflect that reduced test case.  But be sure this produces the behavior you don't understand.

Comment: @David.L Also, the `INSERT` can also contain a subset of columns, as long as your table allows it (no constraint violations).  The easiest is often to reduce the columns in both the `create table` and the `insert` statements to just the minimum required.

Comment: @David.L If you really have a separate question about `INSERT` behavior, just create a new question.  I suspect the question/answer to this is already available in stackoverflow.  `INSERT INTO sometable (col5, col9, col11) VALUES (exp1, exp2, exp3);` or anything like that.  As shown in my answer `INSERT ... SELECT ...;` is fine as well.  My answer shows how to specify the explicit column list as well.

Comment: Thank you! I shall try and put your code into action and check the result.

Comment: @David.L If you have found the answer helpful (or acceptable), don't forget to indicate that with an upvote and/or checkmark.  **No pressure.**  It helps readers understand your conclusions.

Comment: Tried to put it,  but it gave me a red swiggle line in the 'WITH' statement. Tried executing it, and it says that 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'. As well, 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

I tried googling, and put the 'WITH' at the top of the statement. but still gave me the latter incorrect syntax error message (... terminated with a semicolon)